# PHP Custom URL Slug

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a website that is mainly database driven, with a few pages that are hard-coded html files (contact & map). All the other pages are stored in the database.

How can I set my htaccess to allow a user to do do this, while not changing the url at all?

www.website.com/contact
  (-actually loads the contact.html page)

www.website.com/about
  (-actually loads the about.html page)

www.website.com/anything
  (-actually loads page.php?title=anything)

Edit: my updated code

```
RewriteEngine on
# RewriteBase /mcw/
 # i've tried with and without rewritebase

RewriteRule ^(contact|about|index)$ /$1.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(?:contact|about|index)\.html$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(?:admins|css|fonts|img|inc|js)/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /page.php?name=$1
```

Comment: RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L] RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]

Comment: Are you using a router?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
RewriteRule ^(contact|about)$ /$1.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(?:contact|about)\.html$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(?:page\.php|images|scripts|css)/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /page.php?title=$1
```

I am assuming you also have images, css etc that you don't want to rewrite, so as an example I excluded the `/images`, `/scripts` and `/css` diectories. You will need to modify to suit your needs, or remove that line if not needed.

Comment: That looks like it should work! I modified it a tiny bit in regards to the folder, and adding in index.html, and it's giving me a 404. One note, I have this site in a folder called "mcw" on a dev server, would that folder make a difference?

Comment: Please post your modified code in an update to your post, and let me know what is giving a 404. It may be that `.htaccess` files are not being processed on your setup, which means adding `AllowOverride all` to the `<Directory>` in the main config. You can test it by adding something like "blahblahblah" on a line in your `.htaccess` and see if your site gives a server error. If not then `.htaccess` files aren't being processed. It is actually better to put the rules in your main config, but they would need some slight modification for that.

Comment: I updated my code. And yeah, just double checked and htaccess is being processed fine

Comment: Code looks fine. What is giving a 404?

Comment: I really have no idea. it doesn't matter if I try /index.html, /something, or leave it blank. Everything is triggering a 404. I'm messing around with it now, but I'm not having any luck

Comment: Do you have some folder named `/mcw/` containing your site, please explain your site setup. Does `page.php` exist?

Comment: Yes, I have my site stored in /public_html/mcw/. page.php does exist, and takes the name paramater and pulls the appropriate page from the database

Comment: And how is the site served from `/public_html/mcw/`. Is it served as the root of the site? What's the setup?

Comment: Sorry just spotted one error, you need to add `page\.php|` to the start of the exclusions, I edited my answer, but it still doesn't explain `/contact` etc. not working.

Comment: I'm not sure what your're asking. It's a standard cPanel setup. /mcw/ is where all website files are, and anything above that (in the /public_html/) belong to other test projects, but no htaccess files exist above this

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was asking :)

Comment: Please try adding that exclusion and then testing `/contact`. Also test `/contact.html` please and let me know.

Comment: I did, nothing seems to be working. Code looks like it should, but nothing is

Comment: It's very strange that everything is giving a 404, and difficult to diagnose from here. You could try adding `LogLevel rewrite:trace3` to your main config and then seeing what the error log tells you. Not sure how you do that with cPanel though.

Comment: I *think* you need access to the httpd.conf file to add that logging, and I don't have access to that on my test server. Since this might be caused because I have the site in a subdirectory, I'm making a new cPanel account and uploading the site there. I'll let you know if I find anything

Comment: You can add directives to the httpd.conf through cPanel, so it may still be possible to add the logging.